# rChart opens new window in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, rstudio-server

I am trying to plot a rChart in a shiny application and run this via Rstudio server. When I run the app the shiny page gives the error: **attempt to apply non-function** and the RChart opens in a new browser window.

How can make the rChart appear in the shiny application?

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
require(rCharts)

names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$myChart  <- renderChart({
h1 <- hPlot(x = "Wr.Hnd", y = "NW.Hnd", data = MASS::survey, 
type = c("line", "bubble", "scatter"), group = "Clap", size = "Age")
return(h1$show(cdn = TRUE))
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("rCharts and shiny"),

sidebarPanel(),

mainPanel(
showOutput("myChart")
  )
))
```

**My R session info**

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.7.0     plyr_1.8        rCharts_0.3.51  devtools_1.3    ggplot2_0.9.3.1    RMySQL_0.9-3    DBI_0.2-7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the name of the `library` in `showOutput`. If you install the `dev` branch of `rCharts`, then you can run the following code

```
library(shiny)
# devtools::install_github("rCharts", "ramnathv", ref = "dev")
library(rCharts)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("rCharts and shiny"),
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
    mainPanel(
      showOutput("myChart", "highcharts")
  )),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$myChart  <- renderChart2({
      h1 <- hPlot(x = "Wr.Hnd", y = "NW.Hnd", data = MASS::survey, 
        type = c("line", "bubble", "scatter"), group = "Clap", 
        size = "Age"
      )
      return(h1)
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to specify which library need to import depending on which kind of plot you are using.

Here is a [list](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/tree/master/inst/libraries) of all the available libraries from the description of rCharts package.

```
datatables
dimple
highcharts
leaflet
morris
nvd3
polycharts
rickshaw
vega
xcharts
```

Here is the demo code on rcharts website and I modified it to plot hplot.

ui.R

```
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R using highcharts"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
                label = "Choose X",
                choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                selected = "SepalLength"),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
                label = "Choose Y",
                choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                selected = "SepalWidth")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "highcharts")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
require(rCharts)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))
    # HPLOT
    p1 <- hPlot(input$x, input$y, data = iris, type = c("line", "bubble", "scatter"), group = "Species", size = 1)
    # RPLOT
    #p1 <- rPlot(input$x, input$y, data = iris, color = "Species", facet = "Species", type = 'point')
    p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
    return(p1)
  })
})
```

[image]